Laravel Dusk + Sail - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I started a new Laravel application using Sail to have local development running in Docker, so it already started with a selenium/standalone-chrome container also.
Installed Dusk following docs, but running php artisan dusk from sail-8.3/app container gives following error:
  FAILED  Tests\Browser\HomePageTest > example                                                                    UnknownErrorException   
  unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.114)

  at vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:146
    142▕                     throw new UnexpectedAlertOpenException($message, $results);
    143▕                 case 'unknown command':
    144▕                     throw new UnknownCommandException($message, $results);
    145▕                 case 'unknown error':
  ➜ 146▕                     throw new UnknownErrorException($message, $results);
    147▕                 case 'unknown method':
    148▕                     throw new UnknownMethodException($message, $results);
    149▕                 case 'unsupported operation':
    150▕                     throw new UnsupportedOperationException($message, $results);

      +5 vendor frames 
  6   tests/Browser/HomePageTest.php:18
  7   tests/Browser/HomePageTest.php:17

Following other SO answers to same problem I eve tried to run php artisan serve from within app container and then run php artisan dusk, but got the same outcome.
DuskTestCase.php
abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     */
    #[BeforeClass]
    public static function prepare(): void
    {
        if (! static::runningInSail()) {
            static::startChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     */
    protected function driver(): RemoteWebDriver
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
            $this->shouldStartMaximized() ? '--start-maximized' : '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function (Collection $items) {
            return $items->merge([
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless=new',
            ]);
        })->all());

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            $_ENV['DUSK_DRIVER_URL'] ?? 'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}

HomePageTest.php
class HomePageTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     */
    public function testExample(): void
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSee('Login');
        });
    }
}

.env
Added  DUSK_DRIVER_URL=http://selenium:4444
selenium/standalone-chrome container logs
07:43:16.595 INFO [LocalSessionMap.lambda$new$0] - Deleted session from local Session Map, Id: d6234a0ba83b4ac0de1e5c6b70fb616b
07:43:16.595 INFO [GridModel.release] - Releasing slot for session id d6234a0ba83b4ac0de1e5c6b70fb616b
07:43:16.596 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session d6234a0ba83b4ac0de1e5c6b70fb616b
07:43:17.150 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
 [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--window-size=1920,1080, --disable-gpu, --headless=new]}}]
07:43:17.312 INFO [LocalNode.newSession] - Session created by the Node. Id: 8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f, Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 126.0.6478.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 126.0.6478.63 (df799988fdc9..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:45535}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.22.0.6:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 126.0.6478.114, se:vnc: ws://172.22.0.6:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.22.0.6:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
07:43:17.315 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session created by the Distributor. Id: 8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f 
 Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 126.0.6478.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 126.0.6478.63 (df799988fdc9..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:45535}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.22.0.6:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 126.0.6478.114, se:vnc: ws://172.22.0.6:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.22.0.6:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
07:43:17.441 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "a9a833dc373529e36ebc4b22b4b6b57d","eventTime": 1721893397440430947,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute","http.host": "selenium:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "35","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession\u002f8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f\u002furl"}}

07:43:17.869 INFO [LocalSessionMap.lambda$new$0] - Deleted session from local Session Map, Id: 8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f
07:43:17.870 INFO [GridModel.release] - Releasing slot for session id 8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f
07:43:17.872 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session 8b9c90b80c4e711d8781e204ab55331f

I see there is a warning here, but cannot understand it.

OK, found the problem, I missed a step in Dusk documentation related to runnning it with Sail: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail#laravel-dusk
I just needed to run Docker containers using Sail instead of plain Docker command, so
# wrong
docker compose up -d

# correct
./vendor/bin/sail up -d

And then running Dusk tests via Sail too:
./vendor/bin/sail dusk


